# Will my Playstation Plus be affected if I share games with a friend?

Tags: ps4, psn, playstation-plus

Ok, so, this is the situation. I have my primary account on the PS4 with my PS+ account. I want to share games with my friend, he will give me his account to play some games. So, since, from what I understand, I need to put his account as my primary account on the PS4. But since I do that, do I have to deactive as my primary account MY psn? meaning, the PS+ subscription will be affected?

Comment: All I hope that this really is your friend and not some stranger off the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PS+ subscription will remain unaffected. The only thing that will happen is that the other accounts in your PS4 will no longer benefit from your account's PS+ perks.

Keep in mind that:

> - You can activate only one PS4™ system per account.
> - When you activate a system, other users of the system can use applications and enjoy some of the PlayStation®Plus benefits of your account, even if that user is not logged in.

This means that your friend won't be able to have his account activated as primary on his PS4.

Also don't forget the following feature of having a console activated as primary:

> - You can connect to your PS4™ system via the Internet using Remote Play on another device.

Even though you can deactivate this in your PS4's options I wouldn't recommend using someone else's account as a primary account on your PS4 unless you absolutely trust this person.

For more [information on Primary PS4s](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/settings/activation.html).

Comment: Nice info, bro! There's something I´m not sure about it. Can I have more than 1 account per console as primary?

Comment: @Zarathustrax no, just one one account can be the primary account of the console and can only have one console as primary; however, here's a way to workaround it - If your friend deactivates their PS4, and you deactivate yours, you can then switch accounts and use his account and activate your ps4 as primary, now you will be able to play their games in offline mode, and they will be able to play their own games in online mode, and vise versa for your account. (after you re-download all the games, it's tedious and it's not perfect, but it's better than nothing)